# This is about EyeDataGrid

Tags: php, javascript, datagrid

EyeDataGrid can be found at http://www.eyesis.ca/projects/datagrid.html

My question is that how on earth can I select a row and save the data inside the id field of the selected row in a session?

I thought of $x->addRowSelect, but i don't have any idea what's next.
I've tried:

```
$x->addRowSelect("alert('You have selected id # %id%')", EyeDataGrid::TYPE_FUNCTION, 'returnSomething', '%LastName%');
$x->addRowSelect(EyeDataGrid::TYPE_FUNCTION, 'sample');
$x->addRowSelect('sample()');
```

But nothing seemed to work. Because i think addrowselect only accepts JS functions, so i tried type_function, but only guessing what id does, so i can use php functions, but i think type_function is also a php function.

I'm currently up for 36 hours now. Brain cells are critically low, but deadline is critically near too.

Comment: http://www.eyesis.ca/contact.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$x->addRowSelect("session('ID')=%ID%");
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they don't teach the solution.